# Making a quiz and not sure on how to proceed to the next questiion in android using firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code

```
    que = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    opt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    opt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    opt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    opt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    sco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    sco.setText("Score : 0");
    RecieversId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(RecieversId).child("Quiz").child("Question1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            question = dataSnapshot.child("Question").getValue().toString();
            answer = dataSnapshot.child("Answer").getValue().toString();
            option1 = dataSnapshot.child("Option1").getValue().toString();
            option2 = dataSnapshot.child("Option2").getValue().toString();
            option3 = dataSnapshot.child("Option3").getValue().toString();
            option4 = dataSnapshot.child("Option4").getValue().toString();
            que.setText(question);
            opt1.setText(option1);
            opt2.setText(option2);
            opt3.setText(option3);
            opt4.setText(option4);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    opt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option1 == answer){
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                score ++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);
            }
            else
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);
        }
    });
    opt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option1 == answer){
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                score ++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);
            }
            else
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);
        }
    });
    opt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option1 == answer){
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                score ++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);
            }
            else
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);
        }
    });
    opt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option1 == answer){
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                score ++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);
            }
            else
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + score);

        }
    });
```

Hi, I am building a quiz app using firebase.

So this is my logic for question 1. 
After this how do I proceed to question 2? 
Also I am not sure if this logic is right. 
Can some one help me out with this. Database Structure - https://ibb.co/ikxYoy
If you need any more information on the code please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you must keep an array of all your question and answers. and display it by array.index(i)

Comment: Do you want to display all the questions with all the answers in a single activity?

Comment: want a quiz... just show questions in the questions column and change them after choosing the answers